# Please help. I need to add a log file to this multi-threaded rsync script

Tags: shell

## Define source, target, maxdepth and cd to source

```
 source="/media"
    target="/tmp"
    depth=20
    cd "${source}"
```

## Set the maximum number of concurrent rsync threads

```
 maxthreads=5
```

## How long to wait before checking the number of rsync threads again

```
 sleeptime=5
```

## Find all folders in the source directory within the maxdepth level

```
 find . -maxdepth ${depth} -type d | while read dir
    do
```

## Make sure to ignore the parent folder

```
 if [ `echo "${dir}" | awk -F'/' '{print NF}'` -gt ${depth} ]
    then
```

## Strip leading dot slash

```
 subfolder=$(echo "${dir}" | sed 's@^\./@@g')
    if [ ! -d "${target}/${subfolder}" ]
    then
```

## Create destination folder and set ownership and permissions to match source

```
mkdir -p "${target}/${subfolder}"
chown --reference="${source}/${subfolder}" "${target}/${subfolder}"
chmod --reference="${source}/${subfolder}" "${target}/${subfolder}"
    fi
```

## Make sure the number of rsync threads running is below the threshold

```
while [ `ps -ef | grep -c [r]sync` -gt ${maxthreads} ]
do
echo "Sleeping ${sleeptime} seconds" 
sleep ${sleeptime}
done
```

## Run rsync in background for the current subfolder and move one to the next one

```
nohup rsync -au "${source}/${subfolder}/" "${target}/${subfolder}/" 
    </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
    fi
    done
```

## Find all files above the maxdepth level and rsync them as well

```
find . -maxdepth ${depth} -type f -print0 | rsync -au --files-from=- --from0 ./ "${target}/"
```

Comment: You should probably take a look at GNU `parallel` to help with the "multi-threading" bit (although it's not really multi-threading, but multi-processing).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your help. By adding the -v switch to rsync, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after (I don't know what rsync is), but can you not just run the script as,

```
./myscript > logfile.log
```

or

```
./myscript | tee logfile.log
```

(ie: pipe to tee if you want to see the output as it goes along)?

Alternatively...  not sure this is what real coders do, but you could append the output of each command in the script to a logfile, eg:

```
#at the beginning define the logfile name:
logname="logfile"
#remove the file if it exists
if [ -a ${logfile}.log ]; then rm -i ${logfile}.log; fi
#for each command that you want to capture the output of, use >> $logfile
#eg:
mkdir -p "${target}/${subfolder}" >> ${logfile}.log
```

If rsync has several threads with names, I imagine you could store to separate logfiles as `>> ${logfile}${thread}.log` and concatenate the files at the end into 1 logfile.

Hope that is helpful? (am new to answering things - so I apologise if what I post is basic/bad, or if you already considered these ideas!)

Comment: I can delete my answer if you like - then hopefully it will attract more views as an unanswered topic. Sorry to hear it did not work... Does it help to separately redirect stdout and stderr: [here](https://www.itefix.net/content/capturing-all-diagnostic-messages-log-file) ? Or to use rsync specific commands like the second post [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/need-help-to-have-a-rsync-script-log-output-to-a-file-with-time-stamp-913557/) ? Sorry for not knowing rsync better.